# Expo start web not found any modules

Tags: react-native, expo

I got a problem with run `expo start --web`
When I run it I get a lot of errors and warnings related to modules not found.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:19:22
Module not found: Can't resolve './RCTNetworking'

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/WebSocket.js:245:19
export 'default' (imported as 'BlobManager') was not found in '../Blob/BlobManager' (module has no exports)

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/UI/LogBoxNotification.js:94:5
export 'default' (imported as 'View') was not found in '../../Components/View/View' (module has no exports)
```

This is just an example, but in general i have 1 error and 145 warnings
I fixed some errors by webpack

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv)
    config.resolve.alias['../Utilities/Platform'] = 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform'
    config.resolve.alias['./Platform'] = 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform'
    config.resolve.alias['../Utilities/BackHandler'] = 'react-native-web/dist/exports/BackHandler'
    config.resolve.alias['../../Image/Image'] = 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Image'
    config.resolve.alias['../../Utilities/Platform'] = 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform'
    config.resolve.alias["./PlatformColorValueTypes"] = "react-native-web/dist/exports/StyleSheet";
    config.resolve.alias["../../StyleSheet/PlatformColorValueTypes"] = "react-native-web/dist/exports/StyleSheet";
    config.resolve.alias["./RCTAlertManager"] = "react-native-web/dist/exports/Alert";
    config.resolve.alias["./BaseViewConfig"] = "react-native-web/dist/exports/View";
    config.resolve.alias['../Components/AccessibilityInfo/legacySendAccessibilityEvent'] = "react-native-web/dist/exports/AccessibilityInfo";
    return config
};
```

I tried to configure webpack

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by deleting `react-native-pager-view` from project